# Classloading with multiple EARs

Tags: jboss7.x

I have a couple of EARs deployed in JBoss 7 AS.
App1.ear serves as a library to other EARs.
App2.ear has following deployment XML,

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
          <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
          <deployment>
                    <dependencies>
                        <module name="deployment.app1.ear" export="true" />
                    </dependencies>
          </deployment>

          <sub-deployment name="app2_ejb1.jar">
                    <dependencies>
                       <!-- Is it required ??? -->
                       <module name="deployment.app1.ear" />
                    </dependencies>
          </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

JBoss throws following exception while deploying the applications.

Failed to load module: deployment.app2.ear.app2_ejb1.jar:main
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Could not load module deployment.app1.ear:main as corresponding module spec service deployment.app1.ear:main was not found.

If childEAR depends on parentEAR and if the dependencies are specified accordingly in the XML, I would expect subdeployments of childEAR to wait untill parentEAR is successfully & completely deployed.
Does my understanding contradicts the JBoss 7 classloading architecture ?

Can someone provide a solution ?

Comment: Depends on your IDE. Clean and Build both EJB modules.